# Applying a function to pandas dataframe and add a new column?

Tags: python-3.x, function, pandas, dataframe

I got a simple dataframe. It basically looks like this - only much larger.

```
   import pandas as pd
    csv = [{"name" : "Peters Company", "Apples" : 1}, {"name" : "Quagmires Company", "Apples" : 0}]
    df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
```

I trying to apply a little function I wrote to the name column. Here is what I do:

```
from google import search
def get_url(query):
    url = search(query, tld='com', num=1, stop=0, pause=10)
    print(next(url))
```

I am using google to search for a certain `query` and print it afterwords.
I am trying to create a new column `url` which contains the result of `get_url` row by row.

Here is what I did:

```
for i in df.name:
    get_url(i)
```

Obviously, this only results in the `url`getting printed one by one. But I trying to expand the dataframe. I tried my luck with `itterows` and `df.loc`but so far it didn't work out. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apply method is exactly what you want. All you need to do is to add a return value to your function:

```
def get_url(query):
    url = search(query, tld='com', num=1, stop=0, pause=10)
    return next(url) 

df['url'] = df['name'].apply(get_url)
```

If you want to pass other parameters in addition to the name cell, you can use lambda:

```
def get_url(query, another_param):
        url = search(query, tld='com', num=1, stop=0, pause=10)
        return next(url) 

df['url'] = df['name'].apply(lambda column_name: get_url(column_name, another_value))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['url'] = df['name'].apply(get_url)
```

Or [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(url=df['name'].apply(get_url))
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df['url'] = [get_url(x) for x in df['name']]
```

Comment: Glad can help. Do you use from another answer second solution?

Comment: The solution I chose added the `return()` function. It's just a piece I missed...

Comment: Ok, I missed it also ;) Nice day!